# How to Root Lenovo k3 Note Smartphone with Ubuntu

Tags: android, lenovo

I wandered if anyone can give me some advice on how to root the Lenovo k3 Note phone, via Ubuntu. I installed the drivers for this phone and Windows 8 seemed to recognise them. I now need drivers for this phone which are compatible with Linux.I have tried this rooting process with windows 8, but windows refuses to 'mount' the CWM recovery, which is a .img file. I understand that this is a problem with windows. So during the process of trying to root the phone, the commands in the terminal stop responding at the adb and fastboot stage,and the whole thing ends with "waiting for device". This is frustrating and annoying.
 I am very new to Linux. I have just installed Ubuntu 15.04 and my oldest laptop last week and loving it! I would really like to be weaned off Windows eventually as I am keen to join the world of Linux! I do not have a technical background, but I learn fast and would appreciate any guidance you all can give.

Comment: Have you installed `adb` and `fastboot` ?

Comment: Hello.Yes, I have.I unzipped these adb and fastboot files and put them in a named folder. Should I have done something more to install them? The problem occurs at the 'fastboot devices' stage. When I typed the first command, the drivers were recognised and the number associated with the phone came up and then 'device' as I expected. After the bootloader mode, the next command is 'fastboot devices' then a number, same as before plus the word 'fastboot' should come up in response to this command, but it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ADB and FastBoot system-wide and repeat the procedure again:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Comment: Success!! Thank you. I ran the above command in my Ubuntu terminal and fetched abd files. I stayed online during the rooting process and Ubuntu seemed to connect with the phone without any specific installation of drivers. The .img recovery file was instantly recognised by Ubuntu. I've now rooted two K3 notes today, one with CWM recovery and the other TWRP. I could really get used to this rooting business lol! This has also given me confidence to use the terminal, which is great for a newbie like me.

Comment: That great :) I am glad it helped you and give you confidence in using the terminal!

Answer (score 0):

There is a step by step tutorial at [this site](http://karibe.co.ke/?s=root%20lenovo%20k3%20note), install the tools, flash custom recovery and then root the device

Comment: Thanks for this useful tutorial. I installed theTitanium Backup app after rooting and then used it to remove the bloatware.